# KSH script checks for alphanumeric in case statement

Tags: unix, case, ksh

Below is a simplified model of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
#!bin/ksh
string=AUS00
case $string in
[[:alnum:]] ) echo "alphanumeric" ;;
*) echo "nope" ;;
esac
```

I'm unable to validate alphanumeric code.

Constraints:

1. The validation need to happen inside the case statement
2. alnum function is not supported
3. Positive check only. Can't check for the absence of alphanumeric.

Thank you very much

Comment: Also just wanted to bring it to your attention. You missed a slash in your hashbang:

    `#!/bin/ksh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `[[:alnum:]]` will match a **single alphanumeric character**. Your string is longer than one character, so it won't match.

If you want to check that your string **contains** an alnum character, you want `*[[:alnum:]]*`

If you want to check that your string **only contains** alnum characters, I'd flip the check to see if the string contains a non-alnum character:

```
for string in alnumOnly 'not all alnum'; do
    case "$string" in
        *[^[:alnum:]]*) echo "$string -> nope" ;;
        *)              echo "$string -> alphanumeric" ;;
    esac
done
```

```
alnumOnly -> alphanumeric
not all alnum -> nope
```

---

I realized that ksh (even ksh88) implements what bash describes as "extended patterns":

> A pattern-list is a list of one or more  patterns  separated
>        from  each  other with a |. Composite patterns can be formed
>        with one or more of the following:
>
> ?(pattern-list)
>              Optionally matches any one of the given patterns.
>
> *(pattern-list)
>              Matches  zero  or  more  occurrences  of   the   given
>              patterns.
>
> +(pattern-list)
>              Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns.
>
> @(pattern-list)
>              Matches exactly one of the given patterns.
>
> !(pattern-list)
>              Matches anything, except one of the given patterns.

So we can do:

```
case "$string" in
    +([[:alnum:]]) ) echo "$string -> alphanumeric" ;;
    *              ) echo "string -> nope" ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain the rationale for flipping the check. I tried *[[:alnum:]]* and it passes both alpha-numeric and non alpha-numeric strings.

Comment: Due to the fact that `*` is truly a wildcard pattern: it will match anything. So the pattern `*[[:alnum:]]*` means that **any character** can be present before and/or after the alphanumeric character. Presumably, your "non alpha-numeric string" contains at least one alnum character. That's why it's easier to flip the logic: if the string contains at least one non-alnum character, the string cannot be entirely alnum.